# Call a UserForm from module to show pop-up chart and return to same place within module

Tags: vba, excel, charts, userform

I have a VBA program that runs a query to pull data from an oracle database and places it in an Excel worksheet and also create an output .txt file that is used to be uploaded into some other software.

I am trying to put an intermediate step between pulling the data and creating the output file that allows the user to "double-check" that the data going to the output file is correct. I am trying to create a User Form that shows a pop-up chart that allows the user to "accept" or "decline" to create an output file. Below is a basic copy of my VBA code where the macro to pull the data is called and then the output file is created. How do I access the user form and then return to the same place in the module to continue the program?

```
Public Sub OutputSurveyFile()

'Call appropriate macro to run the query to get data needed to be exported to file
  Call qry_DirSurveyRpt
'Set worksheet to the sheet activated by calling query macro
  Set wsData = ActiveSheet

'Determine last row and column of data
 With wsData

  LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 End With

'Store worksheet data to range
 Set rngData = wsData.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

'Store range of data to array
 vData = rngData

'Output desired data to text file and format accordingly
 For i = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)

  If i <> 1 Then

     'Unique well name call
      If vData(i, 1) <> vData(i - 1, 1) Then

'********GO TO USERFORM CREATE POP-UP CHART TO SEE IF USER ACCEPTS OR DECLINES DATA****
'****IF ACCEPT, CONTINUE WITH CREATING OUTPUT FILE BELOW
'****IF DECLINE, MOVE TO NEXT i AND CONTINUE LOOPING THROUGH DATA


         'Directoy path for output file to go
           myFile = sPathFileOutput & myFileName & ".txt"

         fnum = FreeFile()
         Open myFile For Output As fnum

        'Formatting header for new well survey
        Print #fnum, "# FILE HEADER"

    End If

    'Survey data call
    If vData(i, 1) = vData(i - 1, 1) Then

        Print #fnum, vTab & vData(i, 6) & vTab & vData(i, 7) & vTab & vData(i, 8)

    End If

    'Close output text file from editing if next row is a different well
    If i + 1 < UBound(vData, 1) Then

        If vData(i, 1) <> vData(i + 1, 1) Then

            Close #fnum

        End If

    End If

    'Close output test file if end of data range is met
    If i = UBound(vData, 1) Then

        Close #fnum

    End If

 End If

 Next i

End Sub
```

An example of the UserForm pop-up chart to allow the user accept of decline to make an outputfile would be like this:
[image: Pop-Up Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just built this little test macro which should provide a nice shell for you to incorporate into your macro. You're going to have to work out the correct code for all the `If` blocks and what not.

The following code in a stand alone module:

```
Public bSwitch As Boolean

Sub Tester()

MsgBox "Hi"
'this is all your code above the point where you stated you want to call the user form

'call the userform
UserForm1.Show

'user will accept or decline if they 
If bSwitch Then
   'if accept then keep moving with rest of code
    MsgBox "keep moving"
Else
   'if decline go to next i in loop
    MsgBox "end"
End If

End Sub
```

I created a userform with 2 command buttons and the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

bSwitch = True
Me.Hide

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

bSwitch = False
Me.Hide

End Sub
```